# GWT: Send client-side errors/stack traces to server?

Tags: gwt, error-handling

This has to have been asked before, but I haven't had any in searches. I'm looking for a way to catch all client-side obfuscated errors/stack traces and send them to the server for debugging. I did see something about this for javascript using the window.onerror, but I'm looking for a way to do this with GWT, and then display a non-obfuscated stack trace.

Anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

**Edit:**
After working on this for several more hours, I've got the logs going over from GWT to the server via:

```
    GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override 
        public void onUncaughtException(Throwable e) {
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    });
```

That is using the default Logger included with gwt now. this is the relevent .gwt.xml :

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="WARNING" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler" value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="DISABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.developmentModeHandler" value="ENABLED" />  
<set-property name="gwt.logging.systemHandler" value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.popupHandler" value="DISABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.firebugHandler" value="DISABLED" />
<set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordLineNumbers" value="true"/>
<set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordFileNames" value="true"/>
```

I searched everywhere online, and I even found this which is something from gwt-log, which seems like it's before it was implemented into the GWT SDK: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/wiki/GettingStarted#Override_the_default_URL_which_the_RemoteLogger_connects_to

I followed the instructions from the above link, updating the package names and what not. I compile now with the following argument: -deploy war/WEB-INF/deploy/

and this is the relevant part of my web.xml:

```
<!-- Servlets -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RemoteLoggerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.gwt.logging.server.RemoteLoggingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>symbolMaps</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/deploy/**MYAPPNAMEHERE**/symbolMaps/</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RemoteLoggerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/**MYAPPNAMEHERE**/remote_logging</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The end result is that I get the errors, they are just not de-obfuscated. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `initParam` is for the `RequestFactoryServlet`. With the `RemoteLoggingServiceImpl` you're supposed to call its `setSymbolMapsDirectory` method; generally by subclassing the servlet and calling the method from the constructor or `init` method.

Comment: Wait, so can I deobfuscate my logs with a RequestFactoryServlet?

Comment: @spierce7: You don't need the init parameter in your gwt.xml. Simply add `<set-property name="compiler.stackMode" value="emulated" />` to your gwt.xml. Also the -deploy is not necessary if you use the default location, as you are doing

Comment: @HilbrandBouwkamp Hey, thanks for your comment. I don't have an init paramater in my gwt.xml. What is the set-property-name="compiler.stackMode" replace? I'm not sure I understand. I still of course need to have the RemoteLoggingServlet implemented correct? EDIT: so the compiler.stackMode property replaces the recordLineNumbers and recordFileNames?

Comment: Sorry I mean you don't need the init param in your web.xml. The `set-property name` (no dash before name) enabled generation of the mapping files, which are used by `RemoteLoggingServiceImpl` to deobfuscate the client side obfuscated code back to the original Java code.

Answer (score 3):

GWT has built in support for logging, as [detailed in the documentation](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html). There is also support for [sending log messages from the client to the server](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html#Remote_Logging).

You may have to write browser specific code if you want to catch all exceptions. For example, Mozilla have a [window.onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onerror) event, however, I don't think this is standard.

Comment: after doing some more searching, it seems there might be a way to do it with GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler, but then how would I get the error back to the server (AppEngine), unobfuscated, and displayed in the log?

Comment: See the links in my answer above ... add a gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler to your logging config.

Comment: That's correct, but it ended up being so much more than that. I had to implement a remote logging servlet given to us to recieve the remote logs, and configure a bunch of options that aren't even mentioned in that link, so that a log box didn't pop up in the top left of my app. I dunno why the documentation is so incomplete. Anyways, I've got everything working, except for the de-obfuscation. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Agreed, it's much more than what is provided in the documentation. GWT is very well documented as a whole, but the remote logging details fell short IMO